# Populating JasperReports report without parameters in Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

All I want is for my *JasperReports* report to appear, based on the given data source, when I press a button. I can go to *iReport* and see the report as it should be right now, there are no parameters that need to be passed. But I need this to happen when a particular button is pressed on my *jFrame*. A *HashMap* is supposed to be used to pass params and I keep getting a ***NullPointerException*** rather I use null or just an empty *HashMap*. But there's nothing to put in the *HashMap*.

I am also continuously getting this error:
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
(net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Code:

```
        String fileName = "./ArchiveSummary.jasper";
        HashMap hm = new HashMap();
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/full", "root", "");
            if (connection == null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Problems accessing the Database. Program will close.", "Database Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                System.exit(1);
            }
        JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(fileName, hm,connection);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jprint, "./");
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jprint);
        } catch (SQLException sqlE) {
            System.out.println("SQL Error "+sqlE.toString());
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFound) {
            System.out.println("Class not found");
        }catch (HeadlessException exp) {
            System.out.println("ERROR "+ exp.toString());
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
```

The filename is not the null pointer, by the way. 
This code never makes it past JasperPrint....

Edit, The whole exception:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsEnvironment). log4j:WARN
>   Please initialize the log4j system properly. Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.getFormat JRFillTextField.java:706)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.getFormat(JRFillTextField.java:706)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:394)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:368)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:258)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:499)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillBandNoOverflow(JRVerticalFiller.java:439)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillPageHeader(JRVerticalFiller.java:403)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:264)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:247)
>     at
>   PINdiodefuselog.PINdiodeDialog.actionPerformed(PINdiodeDialog.java:268)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Comment: It sounds like your fields are trying to read data from your HashMap, but because there is nothing in it, it's hitting a NPE

Comment: Yes, but I have no params to pass. I even have an example, that works, where they put nothing in the hashmap. But I don't understand why mine is wrong.

Comment: It looks like one or more of your fields is trying to make decisions about the format the field based on the type of the value in the map.  Without the example of the base report, it's going to be hard to make recomendations